# How can the Rails version be checked when a class loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm backporting an ActiveSupport method from Rails 5 into a class within a Rails 4 app. There won't be a naming collision since the class name will be different, but I would like to warn or raise an exception when the class is loaded in Rails 5 (after an upgrade) to remind us to remove the code. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on how you're loading the class. But, to check a version, see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/version.rb — `Rails::VERSION::MAJOR` will be your friend here.

What I would do is hook into `included`

```
class Tracked
  def self.tracked
    @tracked ||= [] 
  end 
end 

module Track
  def self.included(base)
    puts "Woohoo I am included."
    if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 5
      puts "yeah, 5"
    else 
      puts "thanks, DHH"
    end 
    Tracked.tracked << base 
  end 
end 

class Steve
  include Track
end
```